# Advice on Pre-Populating PostgreSQL Table with Ecto

Tags: postgresql, elixir, ecto

TL;DR When playing with Ecto, where (in the code) should I load data to pre-populate a small table after it is created?

I'm learning Elixir, Phoenix, and Ecto. I have a table in my schema to define a list of configurable options. I'd like to pre-populate this table with a minimum set of options when the table is created.

It seems to me that the _create_table.exs script is the place to do that since that's where the table is created. I was looking at an execute{} block but that seems klunky.

Is there a better place in the code to accomplish pre-populating a new table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In *Phoenix*, the common way to populate the DB is to use `priv/repo/seeds.exs` it generates with `mix run` task as:

```sh
mix run priv/repo/seeds.exs
```

But this approach does actually work pretty fine with any *Ecto* project. Simply create the file, put seeding code there, and update your `mix.exs` `aliases` section as

```sh
defp aliases do
  [
    "ecto.setup": [
      "ecto.create",
      "ecto.migrate",
      "run priv/repo/seeds.exs"
    ],
    ...
  ]
```

Now `mix ecto.setup` would create, migrate, *and* fill in the database.